# How to write a Join query in AWS DocumentDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb-mongoapi, aws-documentdb

AWS DoucmentDB is not supporting the $lookup operator, how to write a Join Query in DocumentDB, is there any alternative of $lookup operator in DocumentDB?

Answer (score 4):

Left-outer joins (or correlated subqueries) are written in MongoDB using the $lookup operator.

[Updated 10/16] Amazon DocumentDB now supports $lookup: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-documentdb-add-additional-aggregation-pipeline-capabilities/

You can find the most up-to-date list of supported API/stages/operators here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html

Also, please check the following for recent launches: https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/resources/